# Facing problem with PDF Attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, pdf

I have employee record where I am having a custom Button "GeneratePayslip" after clicking on which I have written a VF page "GeneratePayslip" and on that VF page I select a Month and click generate button, on that click a new VF page is displayed as PDF - "GeneratePayslipPDF". 
I want to attach that generated PDF to the selected Employee after the Payslip is generated. How can I achieve this please guide me to get this problem solve.

I am almost written everything - Attachment, Blob, etc.
Initially i was facing problem of .getContent() method of attachment object, but its solved by putting that code in TRY-Catch.
Now there is no error messages but I did not Found the Attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `try{} catch{}` block didn't solved your problem, it just catch exception and handle it...

About code, try:

```
PageReference thePage = Page./*your page*/;
        thePage.setRedirect(false);
        thePage.getParameters().put(/*your atribute*/ , /*value of atribute*/);
        blob body = null;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
            body = thePage.getContentAsPDF(); 
        }
        // It is here for testing purposes - as you cant call ".getContentAsPDF()" methode in test
        else{
            body = Blob.valueof('Some random String');
        }     
        attachment pdf = new attachment();
        pdf.name = /*name of your attachment*/;
        pdf.body = body;
        pdf.ParentId = /*Id of parent object */;
        pdf.isPrivate = false;

        insert pdf;
```

Comment: Thank You ! for the reply but i have tried the same and one more time I did, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I am getting "System.VisualforceException: system.security.NoDataFoundException: Unable to retrieve object" exception for pg.getContent()

Comment: I guess that is issue of page, are you sure you set all required paramethers?

Comment: Ya, I got the Attachment now, but just its field values are not coming, i might be missing something and I am working on it, let you know if there is any problem again! Thank You !

Comment: See here, what could be possible situation ---http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38756/unable-to-fetch-values-in-pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Shameless self promotion for a simple pattern to accomplish this: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/apex-pattern-save-and-open-pdf-from-button.html

Your code will look something like this:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.ParentId = recordId; // you have to fill in the value of the parent here
attachment.name = 'PDF_'+String.valueof(Datetime.now())+'.pdf';
PageReference pdf = Page.GeneratePayslipPDF;
pdf.setRedirect(true);
try {
  attachment.Body = pdf.getContent();
}
catch (VisualForceException e) {
  attachment.Body = Blob.valueof('There was an error.');
}
attachment.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
insert attachment;
```

Comment: Thank You ! for the reply but i have tried the same and one more time I did, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: See till here am done with ---but problem is  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38756/unable-to-fetch-values-in-pdf